# How DBMS accesses disk pages when OS only allows files access?

Tags: database, b-tree, disk-io

The SQL databases generally use B-trees to store index (and sometimes data as well) in the disk. The B-tree is a tree of disk pages. To create B-tree, the DBMS would require access to pages on the disk. How does DBMS access the disk pages? As far as I know, the operating system allows accessing files on the disk, but not directly the disk pages. So, how DBMS is able to access the disk pages?

I looked at [C++ API](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) for filesystem and I could not spot anything related to accessing disk pages.

Comment: A database "page" is different from an OS "page", you are confusing two different things.

Comment: File access can be random or sequential if your system is running on SSD's performing a seek() probably won't be that costly. Additionally you may want to google for "memory mapped files"

Comment: @Shameel My understanding is that a page (also called disk block) is related to the storage media (hard-disk). It is the smallest unit that can be read or written from hard-disk. I am not sure what a database page or OS page means. Can you please elaborate on what they are and what are the differences between them.